# Adding multiple images on my site - without using plugins

Tags: images

I have a question:

In my child theme, I have added a footer.php, functions.php and styles.php. But, there is still one problem I've still not resolved.

If I use the firebug addon, I see that a particular rectangle has this class: fwidgets. This particular rectangle basically **looks like** an image, which serves as the header for every page.

Even though I might "hide" the rectangle made with a hex number, I don't want to change the CSS to merely add a background image. I need to add more than one image, so that by itself is not a viable solution. The question is, how do you add images in wordpress? I can't find any documention and I've been looking for hours.

That is, I want to modify WP files themselves, and add images in the correct file (but which one is that, and how to I do this? I assume I would need a function? With the functions.php). I am trying to avoid using plugins or anything of the sort, since I want to be able to reuse any coding for multiple themes. I want it to be potentially a simple function, but the codex does not seem to contain what I am looking for.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question, have you seen `add_image_size`, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: All I want to do is to be able to add images to the child-template using (I assume) the functions .php page, so that EVERY page on a website would have those same images. The link you showed me has nothing to do with adding images. That link is about resizing images upon uploading them. I've never hinted about resizing images - I don't know where you got that from.

Comment: You question is confusing as I already stated.

Comment: ? What about my response?? ""All I want to do is to be able to add images to the child-template using (I assume) the functions .php page, so that EVERY page on a website would have those same images."" I can't make it clearer than that. Imagine any website, such as Google. You see the image? If so, pretend that it's a WP website. So, I think to myself: "let's add images, so that every page I am on, has those same new images".

Comment: This depends on the parent theme and where you want to the images added, since no 2 themes are alike, your question is still not answerable.

Comment: lol, BoBoz was able to. But seriously, you are right about no two themes are alike, though they all share one common thing: WP functions and php output. Thank you anyhow for trying to help.

Comment: Is this a multipost for this [question on wp.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/modifying-design?replies=14)?

Comment: I wouldn't call it that :/ as WP and Stackexchange are two different sites. Like a lot of people, I do post on a few sites. Sometimes you never know what solution might be more appropriate. The fact that Wyck claimed he did not understand and claimed it was unanswerable (when in fact BoBoz was able to answer it), is one of the reason I use different websites.

Comment: Wyck, Pieter Goosen, kaiser... why the heck did you put the question on hold??? The question was answered 3 hours before you even put it on hold. That action you took makes no sense o_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

This snippet outputs the image.jpg -image from an images folder in your child theme folder:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: I will read in depth the link you sent me, as it has some interesting information. As for the snippet you provided, seems to work. I will have to play around with the CSS etc., but so far, it looks very promising :)

Thank you :)